# imagick installation in xampp 1.7.3

Tags: php, imagick

I need to PDF file Convert to image using php. so i try to installed imagick and tryed to convert pdf to image but it show in below Error

**Code:**

```
$pagenumber=1;
$myurl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/filename.pdf['.$pagenumber.']';
$image = new Imagick($myurl);
$image->setResolution( 300, 300 );
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$image->writeImage('newfilename.png');
echo $image;
```

**Error :**

> ```
>  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>  'Postscript delegate failed `C:/xampp/htdocs/test/filename.pdf': No
>  such file or directory @ pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/611' in
>  C:\xampp\htdocs\test\image.php:7 Stack trace: #0
>  C:\xampp\htdocs\test\image.php(7):
>  Imagick->__construct('C:/xampp/htdocs...') #1 {main} thrown in
>  C:\xampp\htdocs\test\image.php on line 7
> ```

Comment: Isn't the error saying that the pdf file is not there on the path mentioned?

Comment: thanks for your comment rakesh. pdf file is there correct path only...

Comment: Assuming you are on windows, from where did you get the imagick dll?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some useful info on imagick not able to handle pdf here

```
http://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23879
```

1. Can you try and load the same pdf using ghostscript?
2. What is the version of your pdf file